# Getting error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, object, int, typeerror, iterable

```
    matrix = [
    [3,6,3],
    [6,8,5],
    [8,5,9],
]

for lists in matrix:
    for numbers in lists:
        print(max(numbers)
```

I want to make a code to find out the largest number in a Matrix, but however I get this strange error which I am unable to figure it out. Here's the error

```
  File "C:/Users/AK/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(max(numbers))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: `lists` is one row of your matrix. `numbers` is one integer from a row. `max(numbers)` doesn't make sense because `numbers` is a single integer.

Comment: just delete the nested for loop and use ```print(max(lists))```.
I think that what you was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion appears to be coming from the semantics of your variable names.  For example, take a look at this:

```
for lists in matrix:
```

The `matrix` you have is a "list of lists", this is true.  So then each item in that `matrix` shouldn't be called a "lists", it should be called a "list".  Let's see where that takes us:

```
for list in matrix:
    for numbers in list:
```

Same thing.  *Each element* is not a "numbers", it's a "number":

```
for list in matrix:
    for number in list:
        print(max(number))
```

And now the problem becomes clear.  It doesn't make sense to find the maximum of a "number".  Because it's only one number.  You can print the number:

```
for list in matrix:
    for number in list:
        print(number)
```

But what you appear to be trying to achieve is to find the maximum in each *list*.  Falling back on the semantics that are now more clear, you'd do that on the `list` object:

```
for list in matrix:
    print(max(list))
```